Are there Mackey decompositions for closed subgroups of profinite groups?
$\DeclareMathOperator\ind{ind}\DeclareMathOperator\res{res}$
My question: what is known or expected to be true about the existence of a Mackey decomposition formula in the case of closed subgroups of a profinite group, when neither of the subgroups is open?
A bit more detail: from a literature search, I am certain that no version of the Mackey decomposition formula is published in this level of generality. Is it expected that no Mackey decomposition formula in this level of generality can exist? Is a counterexample known? Is there any folklore around this question?
That is the question. What follows is much more detail, to explain the question. The classical Mackey decomposition formula asserts that, if $G$ is a finite group and $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, then for any representation $M$ of $K$, we have an isomorphism of representations of $H$:
$$ \res^G_H(\ind^G_K(M)) \cong \bigoplus_{\gamma\in H\backslash G/K}\  \ind^H_{H\cap \gamma^{-1} K\gamma}(\res^{\gamma^{-1} K\gamma}_{H\cap \gamma^{-1} K\gamma}\ {}^{\gamma} M),$$
where the direct sum is taken over representatives $\gamma$ for double cosets.
I would like to know about generalizations of this isomorphism to the case where $G$ is profinite, and $H$ and $K$ are closed subgroups of $G$. If $G$ is assumed only locally profinite, and the double cosets $HgK$ for $g\in G$ are assumed to be all open and closed, then in section I.5.5 of Vignéras's book "Représentations $\ell$-modulaires d'un groupe réductif $p$-adique avec $\ell\neq p$," it is claimed that Mackey's decomposition formula also holds when $\ind$ is taken to mean the compact-smooth induction functor. It is also claimed there that, under the same hypotheses, the Mackey decomposition formula holds when $\ind$ is taken to mean the smooth induction functor, and the direct sum on the right-hand side is replaced by a product. See MO user Aurel's answer to this MO question for a clear statement, reproducing this material from Vignéras's book: Mackey theory in the setting of locally profinite groups
My understanding is that there is a missing hypothesis in the second claim. In Yamamoto's paper "On Mackey decomposition for locally profinite groups," an apparent counterexample to the second claim is discussed, but the claim is proven to be true if $K$ is additionally assumed to be an open subgroup of $G$. Yamamoto's example is a locally profinite group which is not profinite (in particular, it is infinite and discrete).
I am interested in the case where $G$ is profinite, in fact, $G$ is a compact $p$-adic analytic Lie group, and $H=K$ is a maximal abelian subgroup of $G$. In these respects, the groups are much nicer than what is allowed by Vignéras's and Yamamoto's more general hypotheses. However, in the examples that I have in mind, $H$ is closed in $G$ but not open, and furthermore, the double cosets $HgH$ are not open in $G$. So neither Vignéras's nor Yamamoto's openness assumptions are satisfied. After combing the literature, I could not find any statement of a Mackey decomposition formula general enough to apply to the situation that I describe. I do not know if it is even reasonable to expect a Mackey decomposition formula to hold in this situation. Is anything known about a Mackey decomposition in this kind of generality?
Thanks for reading.
